# nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field

Tags: spring, rest, jersey-2.0, applicationcontext

I'm trying to wire JERSEY rest services with Spring and i'm facing this exception.

**PodcastResource**

```
package com.integration.messenger.resources;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.integration.messenger.model.Podcast;
import com.integration.messenger.service.PodcastService;


@Path("/podcasts")
@Component
public class PodcastResource {

@Autowired
PodcastService podcastService;

@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public List<Podcast> getPodcasts(){
    return podcastService.getAllPodcasts();
}

/*@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public String getMessage(){
    return "Helooo";
}*/
}
```

**PodcastService**

```
package com.integration.messenger.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.integration.messenger.model.Podcast;

public interface PodcastService {
List<Podcast> getAllPodcasts();

}
```

**PodcastServiceImp**

package com.integration.messenger.service;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.integration.messenger.model.Podcast;
import com.integration.messenger.repository.PodcastRepository;

@Service("podcastService")
public class PodcastServiceImp implements PodcastService {

@Autowired
PodcastRepository podcastRepository;

private Map<Long, Podcast> podcasts = podcastRepository.getPodcasts();

public PodcastServiceImp() {
    podcasts.put(1L, new Podcast(1, "Hello World News", "How to Programme", "www.podcastpedia.com/How to Programme", "Programme"));
    podcasts.put(2L, new Podcast(2, "Hello Jersey News", "Restfull Implementation", "www.podcastpedia.com/Restfull Implementation", "Restfull"));
}

public List<Podcast> getAllPodcasts() {
    return new ArrayList<Podcast>(podcasts.values()); 
}
}
```

**PodcastRepository**

```
package com.integration.messenger.repository;

import java.util.Map;

import com.integration.messenger.model.Podcast;

public interface PodcastRepository {
    Map<Long, Podcast> getPodcasts();
}
```

**PodcastRepositoryImpl**

```
package com.integration.messenger.repository;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.integration.messenger.model.Podcast;

@Repository
public class PodcastRepositoryImpl implements PodcastRepository {

private static Map<Long, Podcast> podcasts = new HashMap<Long, Podcast>();

public Map<Long, Podcast> getPodcasts() {
    return podcasts;
}
}
```

**Podcast**

```
package com.integration.messenger.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Podcast implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1471231465385956738L;

@XmlElement(name = "id")
private long id;

@XmlElement(name = "feed")
private String feed;

@XmlElement(name = "title")
private String title;

@XmlElement(name = "linkOnPodcastpedia")
private String linkOnPodcastpedia;

@XmlElement(name = "description")
private String description;


public Podcast(int id, String feed, String title, String linkOnPodcastpedia, String description) {
    this.id = id;
    this.feed = feed;
    this.title = title;
    this.linkOnPodcastpedia = linkOnPodcastpedia;
    this.description = description;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFeed() {
    return feed;
}

public void setFeed(String feed) {
    this.feed = feed;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLinkOnPodcastpedia() {
    return linkOnPodcastpedia;
}

public void setLinkOnPodcastpedia(String linkOnPodcastpedia) {
    this.linkOnPodcastpedia = linkOnPodcastpedia;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

}
```

**MyApplication**

```
package com.integration.messenger;

import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson1.Jackson1Feature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import com.integration.messenger.resources.PodcastResource;

public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig{
/**
 * Register JAX-RS application components.
 */
public MyApplication() {
    // register application resources
    register(PodcastResource.class);

    // register features
    // register Jackson JSON providers - for the application to understand JSON data
    register(Jackson1Feature.class);        

}
}
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"       
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.integration.messenger" />

</beans>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-Spring-Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.integration.messenger.MyApplication</param-value>          
    </init-param>       
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-Spring-Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> 

<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

</web-app>
```

ERROR:

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'podcastResource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.integration.messenger.service.PodcastService com.integration.messenger.resources.PodcastResource.podcastService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'podcastService' defined in file [C:\My_Workspaces\My_Work\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\messenger\WEB-INF\classes\com\integration\messenger\service\PodcastServiceImp.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.integration.messenger.service.PodcastServiceImp]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: post the full error!

Comment: I have updated the error message. please see above.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to make some configuration related changes to integrate Spring with Jersey. Some I can think of,

1. Register Spring ContextLoaderListener. (This loads the spring xml file).
2. Make use of spring related jersey servlet com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet or org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer(in the latest versions I believe)
3. Specify  in the spring xml file.

-Madhu.

Comment: Hi, I've added those configurations on my web.xml. please see above.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the content. One thing I notice is <context:annotation-config/> is missing. Did you try placing that annotation as well? That is what I wanted to specified in my 3rd item above, but missed it.

Comment: You can ignore my above comment if <component-scan> takes care of doing the job of <context:annotation-config/> tag as well. I have a small confusion there. I know that one of them takes of the other tag but not sure which one is that. :(

Comment: Looking through the exception indicates it threw NullPointerException in the PodcastServiceImp() constructor. The podcasts objects could be null there. You may want to try moving that podcast populate logic into Repository or in a postConstruct method of PodcastServiceImpl. Constructor is called before autowiring so it is resulting in NPE.